# Redirect only web requirements through VPN

Tags: linux, routes, ip, debian, vpn

I have a linux server with Debian and I have set a VPN. This is the route output

```
10.129.21.229   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.129.0.1      10.129.21.229   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
167.114.184.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 venet0
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 venet0
```

For yet I can use this command after launched the VPN to pass all the connection for a single ip through the vpn

```
route add -net 37.187.134.184 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev tun0
```

but i want to pass through the VPN all the web requirements (all the ip with port 80).
I can't pass all my traffic because if I do that than I couldn't no more connect to my server using SSH.

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of how to do this with a single interface. You could try plumbing up a virtual interface and then do your routing that way.

Basically, create a new interface with something along the lines of

```
ifconfig eth0:1 10.0.0.10
```

and then take a look at this page here.

http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/iproute2.html

There is a pretty good walkthrough there. Set up your VPN route over the virtual interface and direct ports 80 and 443 to that. The rest should be able to default route. You can add ports as you find they're needed, like for IM.

-mS